# In TFS 2013, how to prevent backlog items/task/features/epics from being edited?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2013, through the web browser, is there a way to prevent backlog items/tasks/features/epics from being edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can set permissions for editing work items under the "Areas" section.

[image]

Comment: well, i'm out of luck, i don't have permission to do this

Comment: @zurbergram If it's something that needs to be done, and now you know how to do it, can't you ask to the TFS admins / CMs to do that for you? Whoever manages TFS must have the permission to do it.